# How do I hide the originating IP address of a sender in Postfix?

Tags: postfix

I run a small mail service that currently supports a few hundred users. When someone sends mail and someone looks at the source, the persons real IP is contained in, IIRC X-Originating-IP. For user privacy, I don't want their real IP to be displayed anywhere in the headers. I know this can be done as I believe most of the major webmail services do it. Is there a way to do it in Postfix for SMTP?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

and then put the following into `/etc/postfix/header_checks`:

```
/^Received:.*with ESMTPSA/      IGNORE
/^X-Originating-IP:/            IGNORE
/^X-Mailer:/                    IGNORE
/^Mime-Version:/                IGNORE
/^User-Agent:/                  IGNORE
```

Don't forget to `postmap` this file and then reload Postfix.

(Note: It's clear this will hide even more stuff. Adapt as necessary).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize it was _that_ easy to simply ignore whatever headers I wanted. Very cool. Thank you!

Comment: @Anthony Some notes: (1) [You doesn't need to postmap regexp table file](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/first-timer-using-postmap-help-please-tp14908p14909.html) and (2) [By default `mime_header_checks` = $header_checks](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mime_header_checks), so you doesn't need to 'duplicating' the value of `header_checks` to `mime_header_checks`